# Programmatically reload network settings on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, settings, reload

What is the best way to programmatically reload the network settings from the config file `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

At the moment I use the `system` command to execute `ifdown` and `ifup` on the interface, but i'm not happy with this solution.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you want to do ? I'ms not sure I have understood, but maybe you can use a script launched by cron...
In either way, your question should probably be on serverfault, not here.

Answer (score 0):

being more specific would help ...
but,

maybe you could write some script passing the interfaces as parameters
and turning it down and up, the usual way to re-read the /etc/network/interfaces file is that (I think so).

```
for interface in $@
  do
  sudo ifdown ${interface} && sudo ifup ${interface}
done
```

Comment: I use `system("ifdown -a")` and `system("ifup -a")` in my c program to shutdown and restart all interfaces. The problem is, that ifdown and ifup returns always 0 not matter if the command fails or not. The only way to check if the operation was successful is to parse the output of the commands and this isn't realy fail-safe.